# Access97 VBA Export to CSV format issue

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access97 database and I am trying to write some code to export to a CSV file - (I am new to VBA).

I have this working however, there is one field that I am exporting that is a currency so in it for example is £3,456.00 - when I export to the CSV I get exactly this - however I need it to just be the number i.e 3456.00.

On a similar issue - I have the date as dd/mm/yyyy and I wonder if there is a way to convert that in VBA to yyyy-mm-dd?

Please bear in mind any solutions has to be simple due to my limited knowledge!

Comment: What kind of code did you write? A macro to use the export wizard? A loop over a table writing the row's data to a text file? An SQL statement like "INSERT/SELECT INTO ExternalDb"?

Comment: This was in modules and it calls some query that I already set up: DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "olly_csv", "olly aorder export", "\\10.0.0.38\nw_upload\aorders.csv"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the delay; seemingly easy things took longer. As I assumue from your:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "olly_csv", "olly aorder export", "\\10.0.0.38\nw_upload\aorders.csv"
```

that you have an export specification "olly_csv" that determines how to export the
resultset of the SELECT query "olly aorder export" to the file "aorders.csv"
in the destination folder "\10.0.0.38\nw_upload".

The easy way to export the CURRENCY field(s) as plain Double/Float/Single number
and the DATE field(s) with a format of your choice (dd/mm/yyyy) would be to
request just that in the export specification. I found no way to do that in Access
2000 (As far as I can see, there are limited ways to pick date formats, but the features of the Import Wizard to deal with the types of columns are not implemented by the
Export Wizard).

The Docs about "TransferText" [(sorry, Access 2003)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220768%28v=office.11%29.aspx) state:

```
   SpecificationName  Optional Variant. A string expression that's the name of
   an import or export specification you've created and saved in the current
   database. For a fixed-width text file, you must either specify an argument or
   use a schema.ini file, which must be stored in the same folder as the
   imported, linked, or exported text file. To create a schema file, you can use
   the text import/export wizard to create the file. For delimited text files
   and Microsoft Word mail merge data files, you can leave this argument blank
   to select the default import/export specifications.
```

Now there are to schools of Microsoft Docs philology: The optimists will read
that as: If you don't pass an export specification and have a suitable schema.ini
file, then the export process will adhere to the specs in the file. The pessimists
will say: Microsoft never agreed to fullfill your pipe dreams - if you don't
specify an argument for a non-fixed-width file, the TransferText command will
use some obscure default export specification (please pay a consultant to
seek and change it).

Let's be optimistic!

So create a schema.ini file with a section for "aorders.csv". For my tests I
used a table

```
Tabelle: OlliesOrders 
 Name    Typ           Größe
 OrderId Long Integer   4
 Amount  Währung        8
 DateDue Datum/Uhrzeit  8
```

(sorry about the German; Amount is Currency, DateDue Date/Time). For that table
the schema.ini section looks like:

```
[aorders.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
CharacterSet=1252
Format=Delimited(;)
DateTimeFormat=dd/mm/yyyy
Col1=OrderId Integer
Col2=Amount Float
Col3=DateDue Date
```

You'll have to adapt this example to your fields. Do you want column headers? Is the
windows codepage ok? What about field separators? I had to use ; (German locale), you
may need "Format=CSVDelimited". Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for some background. Then call

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "olly aorder export", "\\10.0.0.38\nw_upload\aorders.csv"
```

and check if optimists rule.

For pessimists:

Create a new query on the table to export (from). Change the type to Ausführung/Execute (?)
and edit the SQL until it looks like:

```
SELECT OlliesOrders.* INTO [aorders.csv] IN 'M:\trials\23forum\SOTrials\txt' [TEXT;] FROM OlliesOrders;
```

resp.:

```
SELECT YourFieldsList INTO [aorders.csv] IN '\\10.0.0.38\nw_upload' [TEXT;] FROM YourTable;
```

and execute it (from the query window or a macro/module Sub). My result:

```
"OrderId";"Amount";"DateDue"
1;1411,09;29/04/2011
2;123,45;13/04/2011
```

ADDED: Evidence for my claim, that you can't specify types in the Export Wizard:

Export
[image: Export Wizard]

Import
[image: Import Wizard]

Comment: Post-97 versions of Access have exactly the same options in the export wizard for defining import/export specs as A97 has. I don't know where you get the idea that this is not the case.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: added evidence to my answer; is there an option to enable type picking on export I missed?

Comment: The columns are actually there, they are just hidden. Also, you can set the types by doing the import operation on an appropriately-formatted file, saving the spec and then using it for the export. It's always been that way, so far as I recall, but I did misread what you said -- I thought you said there was a difference in import between current and earlier versions, as opposed to a difference between import and export.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Thanks for the feedback. Perhaps you should post your ingenious (to me) solution of re-using a suitable import spec as an answer (to get at least my vote). One  question, however: Can the type column be unhided?